# Stop push notification in client side

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

Im using ionic framework / cordova for developing my android application. Now i have implemented the push notification using [push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). But i have a page called

> settings

where the client can stop the push notification using a toggle switch. How to implement the toggle switch to stop pushnotification in client slide ? Help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the GCMIntentService class , the onMessage method in the plugin.

Comment: Do you know what SharedPreferences in android are?

Comment: NO im new to android development